# Single Thread Impacts Model Accuracy and Loss with TensorFlow Keras Backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Question**

Why does setting the number of threads in the TensorFlow backend for Keras, `intra_op_parallelism_threads` and `inter_op_parallelism_threads`, to 1 negatively impact the accuracy and loss of a model?

**Background**

I am using Keras (2.1.6) to train an MNIST CNN with TensorFlow (1.7.0) as the backend. I was running some training in an AWS EC2 instance and noticed my accuracy decreased greatly after switching from a t2.medium instance to a t2.small. This happened without changing the code at all between the two instance types.

Given that the number of CPU cores changes from a t2.medium (2 cores) to a t2.small (1 core) I hypothesised that the decrease in accuracy had something to do with threading. In order to test this I forced TensorFlow to use a single thread and ran the training locally.

```
from keras import backend as K
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(),config=config)
K.set_session(sess)
```

Running with a single thread yielded much worse results on my local machine than running multi-threaded.

One single-threaded training run resulted in:

```
train_loss: 2.303228187561035 train_accuracy: 10.75%
```

Whereas a multi-threaded training run resulted in:

```
train_loss: 0.3670464503765106 train_accuracy: 88.00%
```

These results do not make sense to me since, in my mind, running a certain number of training epochs should result in the same amount of computational effort regardless of the number of threads used. My testing results seem to indicate that there is more training occurring with more threads rather than just parallelism being used for speed gains.

I have browsed the Keras repository in GitHub but I haven't found any code that jumps out to me why the results would be so different.

I am calling Keras' *`model.fit()`* to train the model and *`model.evaluate()`* to get the loss and accuracy.

Here are some of my hyperparameters:

```
loss_function: categorical_crossentropy
optimizer: Adadelta
epochs: 12
mini_batch_size: 128
train_size: 600
validate_size: 400
```

**Update 6/26/2018**

I wanted to test the increase in accuracy with more threads independently of my own code so I ran the [Keras MNIST CNN](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) with some changes based on the [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) on reproducible development. My testing code can be seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mistersdevelopment/0b30e4b82bc91f7c1bba5a8bc6e0ba52). The only difference between the two Python files in the gist are lines 80, 90, and 91. Uncommenting those lines forces the TensorFlow backend to run on a single thread.

I ran *`mnist_cnn_single_threaded.py`* three times and *`mnist_cnn_multi_threaded.py`* three times. The results can be seen in the same [gist](https://gist.github.com/mistersdevelopment/0b30e4b82bc91f7c1bba5a8bc6e0ba52#file-testing_results-txt). They fit with the results I found running my own model yesterday locally and in EC2.

**Testing Results**

Here are my testing results per NPE's comment. Running with an explicitly set, but default `tf.ConfigProto()` yielded similar results to not setting the thread values at all. In the chart and table below "threads" equates to setting both `intra_op_parallelism_threads` and `inter_op_parallelism_threads` to the specified value.

[image: Loss and Accuracy vs Threads]

```
Threads   Test Loss     Test Accuracy
1         2.300546171   0.1141
2         0.060040779   0.9806
4         0.060651763   0.9805
6         0.06015457    0.9808
8         0.057530957   0.9819
```

The only case that makes a noticeable difference in the accuracy and loss is explicitly setting the threads to one.

**Update 6/27/2018**

This appears to only be an issue with the TensorFlow backend to Keras. I tried the test using the Theano backend, with the options below to force a single thread, and I did not notice the accuracy/loss issue.

```
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = "device=cpu,force_device=True,openmp=False"
```

Comment: Occasionally, I have seen MNIST CNNs get stuck in low accuracies, due to unfortunate initialization. Are you sure that the low accuracy is correlated with the single-thread, and it is not just a spurious result (fluke)? Try repeating the experiment some times...

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut. I followed the Keras FAQ on reproducibility and I was able to see similar results with repeated testing. I updated the original post to reflect that.

Comment: Personally, I would conduct two experiments to gather more data: (1) test with an explicitly constructed but default config (`config = tf.ConfigProto()`); (2) run with 1, 2, 4, 8 etc threads to see what happens to test and val accuracy in each case.

Comment: @NPE that's a good idea. I will try that and report the results. Thank you.

Comment: Is it relevant now also? Is it beneficial to upgrade the core counts?